# Simple-Form and required fields: doesn't treat as required if condition added to validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form, required

Simple-Form automatically detects whether there is a `validates :xxx, presence: true` validation, and displays the field as a required one (e.g. with an asterisk appended to the label).

```
validates :parent, presence: true
```

This results in:

[image: asterisk]

Interestingly, as soon as I add a condition to this validation...

```
validates :parent, presence: true, if: -> { true }
```

...it doesn't do this no more:

[image: no asterisk]

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, validations are only run when you save the object to the db, so you have no way of knowing whether the lambda returns true or not until then. Of course in your case it always returns `true`, but imagine you have a time constraint in your lambda or some other more complex condition, e.g.

```
...., -> { Time.zone.now > Date.new(2017, 1, 1) }
```

Maybe when you create the object for the form this returns `false`, but when the form is actually submitted and saved to the db enough time had passed for it to return `true`.

So there is no way for simple_form to know when the form is created whether the field is required or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it a feature, since it's deliberate. If you look at the gem code (especially at [calculate_required](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/helpers/required.rb#L10) and [conditional_validators?](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/helpers/validators.rb#L22)) you'll notice that if the presence validator has a condition, like `if` or `unless`, the field is no longer marked as required.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this for `:terms` being a checkbox element:

```
validates :terms, presence: true, acceptance: true
```

With this, it validates at form level for checking that 'term' checkbox is submitted only after it's checked. Hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Simple form validations don't work if you have conditions in your validations.

This is intentional as you can put whatever you want in an `:if` or `:unless` and calling this could cause unintended side effects.

source: https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/issues/322